# How to add an active class when the button is clicked and remove the active class from other buttons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, react-hooks

There are five buttons. When one of these buttons is clicked, the active class must be added and the others must be deleted. How can I do this with react? Buttons are not links.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRChV.png)

```
<ul>
    <li className="active">
        All
    </li>
    <li>
        Draft
    </li>
    <li>
        Under assessment
    </li>
    <li>
        Need data
    </li>
    <li>
        Ready
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: jquery: $("li").on('click', evt => { $("li.active").removeClass('active'); $(evt.target).addClass('active') }). translate to typescript or javascript as you desire for react.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using className. That probably means you are using react. If you are, then please do not use jquery. JQuery and React do not like each other. JQuery manipulates the dom, whereas React schedules updates to its own virtual dom.

You could do something like this. Create two classes, active and inactive (or whatever you want to call them). Add a click event to it and have that click set the index. Then you can set it as active or not by the index.

```
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = React.useState(0);

  const handleOnClick = index => {
    setActiveIndex(index);
  };
  const boxs = [0, 1, 2, 3];
  const box = boxs.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <li
        key={index}
        onClick={() => handleOnClick(index)} // pass the index
        className={activeIndex === index ? "active" : "inactive"}
      >
        {item}
      </button>
```